# Setting listview item background image to drawable downloaded from the web

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm downloading an image from the web and trying to set it as the background to the inflated list element in my ListView adapter. This is my method (from the class extending `BaseAdapter`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    //working with an object called "hl"
    if (view == null){
        view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element, null);
    }

    Bitmap background = hl.getBgImage();
    Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(background);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.layout.headline_list);
    rl.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
    return view;
}
```

However, I am getting a NullPointerException on the `rl.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);` line. Is there a problem with the way I'm adding the image? My method to get the bitmap is as follows, the stack trace is never called so I assume that it is downloading properly?

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Edit: I am calling `getBitmapFromUrl(String imageURL)` with:

```
    String image = "http://www.google.com/trends/resources/2327917647-google-icon.png";
    Bitmap bg = getBitmapFromURL(image);
    Object hl = new Object(title, bg);
    objectList.add(hl);
```

Comment: post the code where you used the getBitmapFromURL

Comment: Just tried putting it in an imageview and it works, so the problem is not with getting the image. It must be within the adapter.

Comment: can you post the whole class where you post the below code

Comment: Is it a problem finding the layout item with id `headline_list`?

Comment: I solved it. And no, the issue was with the next line, actually setting the background on the relative layout. I should have been setting it on the view instead. I have added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Should have ignored the relativelayout completely.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    //working with an object called "hl"
    if (view == null){
        view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.headline_list, null);
    }

    Bitmap background = hl.getBgImage();
    Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(background);
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: after get image you must save Bitmap image to one place for loading in next time ( after scrolling ).

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the code line "rl.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);" will never throw NullPointerException unless rl is null, even if dr is null. So Please update your xml file R.layout.list_element and let's find the problem together.
Good Luck!